# Erro ao tentar subtrair 2 listas em Python

Tags: python, array, algoritmo, syntax-error, back-end

Estou tentando transformar o seguinte algoritimo em python:

`Programa_Matrizes

var

I : inteiro

A : conjunto[1..20] de real

B : conjunto[1..20] de real

C : conjunto[1..20] de real

início

para I de 1 até 20 passo 1 faça

leia (A[I])

leia (B[I])

C[I] ← (A[I] – B[I])

fim_para

para I de 1 até 20 passo 1 faça

escreva (A[I])

fim_para

para I de 1 até 20 passo 1 faça

escreva (B[I])

fim_para

para I de 1 até 20 passo 1 faça

escreva (C[I])

fim_para

fim`

Comecei fazendo assim:

```
for i in range(20):
    A = int(input([i]))
    B = int(input([i]))
    C[i] = (A[i])-(B[i])
```

Mas ao executar me aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Ocorreu uma exceção: TypeError
'int' object is not subscriptable

line 5, in <module>
    C[i] = (A[i])-(B[i])
```

Ajude-me pfv

Comment: é assim que acha que é uma lista em python `A = int(input([i]))`  bem diferente as lista são criado fora do **loop**   `A=[]`     ou   `A = list()`  ... dentro do loop :    `A.append(i)`   ou     `A =A +[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repare na seguinte linha:

```
A = int(input([i]))
```

A variável A é criada como tipo `int`, ou seja, não é uma lista.

Consequentemente, na linha `C[i] = (A[i])-(B[i])`, quando se tenta aceder ao elemento `i` de A e de B, dá erro, uma vez que não são listas.

Não é claro como é que se pretende construir, as listas, portanto aqui vão duas possibilidades.

```
A = [] # isto inicializa A como uma lista
B = [] # isto inicializa B como uma lista

for i in range(1, 6):

    A.append(i) # acrescentar cada valor de i a lista A
    B.append(int(input("introduzir numero")))
```

A será então: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Para B, se eu introduzir 10, 20, 30, 40 e 50 (um de cada vez quando for pedido), B será: `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`

Agora já podemos aceder a um elemento de A, `A[i]`, uma vez que A é uma lista e não um int.

Pretende-se agora criar uma nova lista, C, somando cada valor de A com o valor correspondente de B.

Podemos fazer:

```
C = [] # criamos C como uma lista

for i in range(len(A)):
    C.append(A[i]+B[i])
```

Isto usando um for. Podemos, no entanto, escrever C em apenas uma linha:

```
C = [A[i] + B[i] for i in range(len(A))]
```

(Ou até C = [x+y for x, y in zip(A, B)]...)

Podemos fazer C[i] = A[i] + B[i]? Sim, se C já tiver sido criada previamente com uma quantidade de elementos correspondente ao número de elementos em A e B. No entanto, criar C com valores que não seriam definitivos, seria apenas aumentar a confusão no código, não se acrescentado nada, uma vez que podemos criar C pelas formas acima apresentadas.